# XML - Cannot move product.info.review after product.info.overview

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, xml, layout-update

I'm trying to do the following, moving product.info.review after product.info.overview (short description) 
[image: screenshot]

I've used the following code, but it is not working:

```
<move element="product.info.review" destination="content" after="product.info.overview"/>
```

I've checked if I have the right element by removing it:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"/>
```

Above code worked...

Edit for Rakesh:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="productpage.image" template="xxx_xxx::productpage.phtml" after="product.info.main"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info" destination="content" after="productpage.image"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to just keep below line in default.xml file or catalog_product_view.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Removed all files in pub/static, reindexed and cleared cache, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Have you add above line in default.xml file?

Comment: No, in my own module i've overwritten the catalog_product_view.xml file. The other changes i've made in that file are shown on the frontend.

Comment: please share your xml code

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Above code(Your updated code) is working fine for me..

Comment: Tried it in default.xml as well didn't work...

Comment: Tried the following code, also not working.... ` <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.media" after="product.info.main"/>`

Comment: <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
just keep above code

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet (still looking), above code doesn't work in my enviroment..

Comment: Just try with above code its working fine for me, if not work please let me give full path of xml file

Comment: The edited code in your answer doesn't work for me...